# how to group equal data and show it in the template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have an app that shows the history of products ordered in a restaurant, and to get the data of the restaurant, i have the following view:

```
def restaurant_orders(request):

    restaurant = get_restaurant(request.user.restaurant.user_id)
    
    products = list(restaurant.restaurante.values_list("id"))

    items = Item.objects.filter(product_id__in=products).order_by('order_id')

    context = {'items': items}

    return render(request, 'pages/orders_restaurant.html', context)
```

In template i'm displaying as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <h2>Histórico de Pedidos</h2>
    {% for value in items %}
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>    
        <li class="list-group-item bg-light">
        <h4>Order {{ value.order_id }}</h4>
        {{ value.quantity }} X {{ value.product }}
        <span class="float-right">R$ {{ value.price }}</span>
            <li class="font-weight-bold list-group-item bg-light">Client Name
                <span class="float-right">{{ value.order.name }}</span>
            </li>
        </li>
             <br> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

but doing it this way I get each data separate, and I would like to know if there is any way to group the data that has a field with the same value. The result I getting now is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUcLF.jpg), and I would like something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE7Rq.jpg).

**model.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="order_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators= [
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(20),
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need loop over a `Order` model query.
You can filter it throught the related name property in the `Item` model.

```py
orders = Order.objects.filter(items__product_id__in=products)
```

Then, in your template, you can loop through the orders and the items in each one's:

```html
<ul> {# apply your markup... #}
  {% for order in orders %}
    <li>
      {{ order }}
      <ul>
        {% for item in order.items.all %}
          <li>{{ item.product }} {# ... #}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: worked perfectly, I had already tried to filter by the `Order` model, but I didn't know how to use the related name, ty